# Как на C# отслеживать количество дисков в системе и реагировать, когда подключили флеш накопитель или диск?

Tags: c#

Как на C# отслеживать количество дисков в системе и реагировать, когда подключили флеш накопитель или диск?

Comment: [похожий вопрос на английском](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16245706/check-for-device-change-add-remove-events)

Comment: @Grundy: Пришёл оставить этот же комментарий :)

Comment: @VladD, а я думал ответ хороший напишешь :-)

Answer (score 2):

Для этой задачи прекрасно подходит WMI:

```
using System;
using System.Management;

public sealed class DriveVolumesWatcher
{
    public event EventHandler<VolumeChangedEventArgs> VolumeArrived = delegate { };
    public event EventHandler<VolumeChangedEventArgs> VolumeRemoved = delegate { };

    public DriveVolumesWatcher()
    {
        ManagementEventWatcher watcher = new ManagementEventWatcher
            {
                Query = new WqlEventQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_VolumeChangeEvent WHERE EventType = 2 OR EventType = 3")
            };
        watcher.EventArrived += Watcher_EventArrived;
        watcher.Start();
    }

    private void Watcher_EventArrived(object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e)
    {
        ushort eventType = (ushort)e.NewEvent.GetPropertyValue("EventType");
        string driveName = (string)e.NewEvent.GetPropertyValue("DriveName");
        switch (eventType)
        {
            case 2:
                VolumeArrived(this, new VolumeChangedEventArgs(driveName));
                break;
            case 3:
                VolumeRemoved(this, new VolumeChangedEventArgs(driveName));
                break;
        }
    }
}

public sealed class VolumeChangedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public readonly string DriveName;

    public VolumeChangedEventArgs(string driveName)
    {
        DriveName = driveName;
    }
}
```

Использование:

```
var driveWatcher = new DriveVolumesWatcher();
driveWatcher.VolumeArrived += (o, e) => { MessageBox.Show("Inserted " + e.DriveName); };
driveWatcher.VolumeRemoved += (o, e) => { MessageBox.Show("Removed " + e.DriveName); };
```

**Не забудьте добавить референс на `System.Management` в проект.**